# Delete items from a list before a specific keyword

Tags: python

We scraped website data into a list with many irrelevant data in the beginning. How do we delete rows containing strings and floats until a specific keyword upon which it should keep the data in the list.  For example:

We call our list `ls` with values like this:

```
None
bla2 
'11111.3434'
bla3
'1.43'
**Keyword** 
'1.43332'
Bla 4
```

We want to delete everything before the keyword and keep everything after the keyword in the same list structure.

It might be a very easy task, but we're just getting started with Python and got stuck with this part and couldn't find a suitable answer yet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `index` method of lists and slicing: `ls[ls.index(keyword)+1:]`. (note: this will raise error if keyword is not in the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you didn't mention that the key word can repeat itself it can be done with a single for loop

```
ls = [None, 'bla2', '11111.3434', 'bla3', '1.43', 'imakeyword', '1.43332', 'Bla4']
keyword = 'imakeyword'
for item in ls:
    if item == keyword:
        pos = ls.index(item)
        new_ls = ls[pos:]

print(new_ls)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.index()` to get the index, and `del` to delete

```py
l = [None, 'bla2', '11111.3434', 'bla3', '1.43', 'Keyword', '1.43332','Bla 4']
del l[0: l.index('Keyword')]

print(l)
```

```
['Keyword', '1.43332', 'Bla 4']
```

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to keep everything *after* the keyword, not including it. If that's the case, simply do `l.index('Keyword')+1`.

Comment: `We want to delete everything before the keyword`. A little bit ambiguous. I hope OP will understand the logic. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)

```
import itertools
l = list(itertools.dropwhile(l, lambda i: i!=keyword))
```

Or you can use any filtering expression you like for the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Can try using slicing the list, an example can be this one

```
filter_list = lambda string_list, target_keyword: string_list[string_list.index(target_keyword)+1:]
```

After only need to call the method to perform the filter like this:

```
your_var = filter_list(x, 'Keyword')
```

Full example code

```
x = [None, 'bla2', 'test3', 'qweqw', 'eje', 'bu']

filter_list = lambda string_list, target_keyword: string_list[string_list.index(target_keyword)+1:]

print(filter_list(x, 'test3'))
```